# Do WebGL fragment shaders support outerProduct?

Tags: matrix, opengl-es-2.0, webgl, fragment-shader

When compiling this WebGL fragment shader in both Chrome 22 and Firefox 15:

```
precision mediump float;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform sampler2D u_tex;
void main() {
    vec2 texCoord = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution;
    vec4 floatColor = texture2D(u_tex, texCoord);
    mat3 outerMat = outerProduct(floatColor.rgb,floatColor.rgb);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(outerMat[0], 1);  
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: 0:8: 'outerProduct' : no matching overloaded function found
ERROR: 0:8: '=' :  cannot convert from 'const mediump float' to '3X3 matrix of float'
```

The OpenGL ES 2.0 GLSL spec indicates that `mat3 outerProduct(vec3,vec3)` is supported, and the WebGL spec says that it accepts ES shaders, so I'm not sure what's going wrong. Is outerProduct not supported in WebGL fragment shaders, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `outerProduct` function in OpenGL ES 2.0 GLSL. Where did you read that there was? (or am I missing it?)

Here's the spec
http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf

Comment: Ah, it seems that the documentation from Khronos has outerProduct, but only for ES3. See http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/manglsl/ Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `mat3 outerMat = outerProduct(vec3(floatColor.rgb),vec3(floatColor.rgb));`

To expand, maybe giving it an explicit type is better than using .rgb.

Answer (score 0):

it is now available with webGL2. 
Check your system here: https://webglreport.com/?v=2